# how to avoid memory leak when throwing exception between a c++ non clr to clr dlls?

Tags: c++, memory-management, interop, clr

In my solution i have some c++ projects (dlls) which are clr enabled as they are using a c# (.NET) dll.

When throwing exception between non clr project (dll) to the one with the clr enabled and catching it **by reference**, i detected a memory leak. When i omitted the use in the c# dll, and changed the project to be non clr the leak is gone.

Alternatively, if i will throw **new  Exception** and delete it within the catch statement - the leak is gone.
the Exception class is inherits from std::exception with some more strings for general description, function name and some more.

Can sombody explain the leak, or how can i avoid that leak ?

Comment: Well, when you "throw new T;" you new something, so someone has to delete it. Whats wrong with just throwing an instance without new?

Comment: the leak is when i tried to throw instance (without new ) and catch it by reference

Comment: Please tag your question correctly; shouldn't there be a `clr` and `net` tag or something?

Comment: Thanks, my first question here...

Answer (score 3):

different dlls compiled with different compiler/compiler settings are generally not compatible regarding the layout of objects & memory allocation & de-allocation. This is the reason why you should avoid allocating an object in one dll and de-allocating it in another dll. As you noticed, this might lead to memory leaks.

If you want to pass error-information across module boundaries, pass them via error code or via a mechanism that takes care of that (e.g. SEH exceptions or COM exceptions)

---

Ok, here some clarifications:

1. An object consists of 2 parts - data and code. An object instance is the data and the knowledge which code needs to be called when. For non-virtual function this knowledge is resolved at compile time, for virtual functions it is resolved at run-time via a pointer (this) in the data.
2. Allocation: the data must be allocated somewhere. There are 2 possibilities - the stack and the heap. The stack is generally used for small data. It has some benefits like automatic de-allocation of the object when the scope is left. The stack also stores return addresses and so on. Whenever "new" is called to allocate an object, it is allocated on the heap. The normal space for the stack is 1 or 2 MByte whereas the heap size is in a range of multiple GB for modern computers. For that reason, every larger application uses the heap for the majority of its data structures. Sometimes this is hidden behind the object - an example for that is std::vector. The data inside the vector is stored on the heap whereas the object managing this buffer can be on the stack.
3. Object layout & heap memory management: The size of an object may differ between different compiler implementations & settings. An example is the size of the containers in visual studio. Some compiler implement additional helper member that are only available in Debug and that increase the size if the code was compiled in debug. Additionally, the memory allocation & deallocation routines can be different in debug & release to detect memory allocation & de-allocation errors, uninitialized variables and so on. These 2 facts lead to the simple conclusion: never de-allocate in a different module than the one where you allocated the memory (exception: if you can control the compile settings). This rules out exceptions as well.

Comment: even if i'm throwing an instance (object) ?

Comment: The reason for that is different heaps used for memory allocation.

Comment: Can u please explain why  instance of object is allocated on heap ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still why if i throw new Exception i manage to catch it and delete the Exception memory without any leak, even though allocation and de allocation are in seperated (dll) projects, one (the catching) is clr enabled and the one that throw is non clr ?